# Passing props to popup in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in ReactJS. I am building a web app to display users list and onclick each row there will be a popup to display more information.

Code --

Table component

```
class Table extends Component
{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { showPopup: false };
    }

 togglePopup(user) {
    console.log(user)
    axios.get(user.href).then( response =>{
                   .......
    }
    this.setState({
                showPopup: !this.state.showPopup
            });
}

----------------------------------
----------------------------------

{ (this.props.users.length > 0) ? this.props.users.map( (user, index) => {
        return (
             <tr key={ index }>
               <td>{ user.name }</td>
               <td>{ (user.age != null && user.age > 0) ? user.age : '--' }</td>
               <td>{ user.phone }</td>
               <td>{ (user.cmp != null && user.cmp > 0) ? user.temperature : '--' }</td>
               <td><button onClick={this.togglePopup.bind(this,user)}>View</button></td>
             </tr>
          )
       }) : <tr><td colSpan="5">Loading...</td></tr> }

{this.state.showPopup ?
                    <Popup banksDetail = { this.state.banksDetail }
                           user = { this.props.user }
                        text='Click "Close Button" to hide popup'
                        closePopup={this.togglePopup.bind(this)}
                    />
                    : null
                }
```

Couple of issues are here

1. On togglePopup function `user.href` is undefined when I close the popup window.
2. Inside Popup component declaration `user = this.props.user` is undefined

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Popup` calls its `closePopup` prop with whatever arguments it wants.  For example if it calls `closePopup(someMouseEvent)`, then in `togglePopup`, `user` will be set to `someMouseEvent`.  `onClose={togglePopup.bind(this, user)}` would work because it ensures `user` gets passed as the first argument to the bound function before any arguments `Popup` passes, so if it calls `closePopup(someMouseEvent)`, `togglePopup` will actually get called with `(user, someMouseEvent)`.

I don't know what `star` is or why you have `onClick={this.togglePopup.bind(this,star)}` but that seems to be a mistake.  I think you want `user` instead of `star` there.

Regarding question 2 it seems like what you probably want is to put `user` into `this.state`; in `togglePopup`, call `this.setState({user, showPopup: !this.state.showPopup})`, and in `render` pass `<Popup user={this.state.user} />`.

Not sure how you were thinking `togglePopup(user)` would affect `this.props.user`, but it's a misunderstanding.  The only way `this.props.user` will have a value is if you render `<Table user={...} />`.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the whole code and I was fearing someone would vote me negative. Thank you for your help. yes actually the single user details was needed to put under a state that's what I didn't do. It seems it's working fine now. In `<Table...` I am sending the whole resultset. So basically this table is a child component of another component and popup is a child of Table. I have updated the post now.

Comment: No worries!  People probably will vote it negative but don't take it personally, it's just that questions like this are of limited use to other people because it's not very likely someone with the exact same confusion will find this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `togglePopup` method is not aware of the user props you are sending to the popup component as it lives outside of it. If you want to pass the user to `togglePopup` you could do it by returning the `togglePopup` with the user argument using es6 syntax:

```
closePopup={() => this.togglePopup(user)}
```

and binding togglePopup in the constructor:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { showPopup: false };
        this.togglePopup = this.togglePopup.bind(this);
    }
```

As for your second question, you are sending this.props.user to the Popup component which is probably undefined. You need to give it the user like this assuming user is an object:

```
user = { user }
```